# Get progress of directory compress with Quazip

Tags: c++, qt, quazip

Is there anyway to get the progress from QuaZip when using the JlCompress function?

Here's the way I'm using it:

```
JlCompress::compressDir(outputFile, inputDir, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently there is no way. You'll have to use `QuaZip` and `QuaZipFile` directly. You could use `JlCompress` code for starters so you don't have to implement the whole thing from scratch.

Even better yet, modify `JlCompress` to suit your needs and then contribute the code back! So you'll have the desired functionality in the next QuaZIP version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer